# LightningChart JS PolygonSeries capturing mouse interactions

Tags: lightningchart

I am using v3.4.0 and adding a Polygon Series. I don't want the shapes in the series to capture any mouse events. It's currently capturing mouse clicks, which are intended for the background, and specifically **onSeriesBackgroundMouseDoubleClick**.

```
 const series = chartL.addPolygonSeries()
      .add(points);
    series.setMouseInteractions(false);
```

From what I understand **setMouseInteractions** should disable any mouse events for the polygon series? Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue here is around the way PolygonSeries is separated to the Series itself and any number of "PolygonFigures" you can create within it.

The `PolygonSeries.add` method creates and returns a new figure, so actually your `series` variable holds a reference to the figure, not the series.

The code still looks valid and doing `PolygonFigure.setMouseInteractions` should by all common sense disable mouse tracking on it, but I have a feeling there might be a bug on this.

I would suggest you try also disabling mouse interactions on the Series, so something like:

```
 const series = chartL.addPolygonSeries()
      .setMouseInteractions(false)
      
 const figure = series.add(points).setMouseInteractions(false);
```

Seems silly, but I think it might work as an immediate solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but I decided to upgrade to v4, and was able to solve this there. However, I think the issue here was that setMouseInteractions() should be directly on series, since add() returns a different object.

Comment: If the problem is resolved in the newer version then that's all good :)